# Delete older from a duplicate select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been working on a query to search and delete duplicate column values. Currently I have this query (returns duplicates):

```
SELECT NUIP, FECHA_REGISTRO
FROM registros_civiles_nacimiento
WHERE NUIP IN (
 SELECT NUIP
 FROM registros_civiles_nacimiento
 GROUP BY NUIP
 HAVING (COUNT(NUIP) > 1)
) order by NUIP
```

This work returning a table like this:

```
NUIP        FECHA_REGISTRO
38120100138 1975-05-30
38120100138 1977-08-31
40051800275 1980-09-24
40051800275 1999-11-29
42110700118 1972-10-26
42110700118 1982-04-22
44030700535 1982-10-19
44030700535 1993-05-05
46072300777 1991-01-17
46072300777 1979-03-30
```

The thing is that I need to delete the rows with duplicate column values. But I need to delete the row with the oldest date, for example, for the given result, once the needed query is performed, this is the list of result that must be **kept**:

```
NUIP        FECHA_REGISTRO
38120100138 1977-08-31
40051800275 1999-11-29
42110700118 1982-04-22
44030700535 1993-05-05
46072300777 1991-01-17
```

How can I do this using plain SQL?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the rows from the database or just remove them from your query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff To remove them from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--PULL YOUR SELECT OF RECS WITH DUPES INTO A TEMP TABLE 
--(OR CREATE A NEW TABLE SO THAT YOU CAN KEEP THEM AROUND FOR LATER IN CASE)
SELECT   NUIP,FECHA_REGISTRO
INTO #NUIP 
FROM     SO_NUIP
WHERE NUIP IN (
SELECT NUIP
 FROM SO_NUIP
 GROUP BY NUIP
 HAVING (COUNT(NUIP) > 1)
)

--CREATE FLAG FOR DETERMINIG DUPES
ALTER TABLE #NUIP ADD DUPLICATETOREMOVE bit

 --USE `RANK()` TO SET FLAG
 UPDATE #NUIP
 SET DUPLICATETOREMOVE = CASE X.RANK
        WHEN  1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 
        END
--SELECT *
FROM #NUIP A
INNER JOIN (SELECT NUIP,FECHA_REGISTRO,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [NUIP] ORDER BY    FECHA_REGISTRO ASC) AS RANK
FROM #NUIP) X ON X.NUIP = A.NUIP AND X.FECHA_REGISTRO = A.FECHA_REGISTRO

--HERE IS YOUR DELETE LIST
SELECT * 
FROM so_registros_civiles_nacimiento R
JOIN #NUIP N ON N.NUIP = R.NUIP AND N.FECHA_REGISTRO = R.FECHA_REGISTRO
WHERE N.DUPLICATETOREMOVE = 1

--HERE IS YOUR KEEP LIST
SELECT * 
FROM so_registros_civiles_nacimiento R
JOIN #NUIP N ON N.NUIP = R.NUIP AND N.FECHA_REGISTRO = R.FECHA_REGISTRO
WHERE N.DUPLICATETOREMOVE = 0

--ZAP THEM AND COMMIT YOUR TRANSACTION, YOU'VE STILL GOT A REC OF THE DELETEDS FOR AS LONG AS THE SCOPE OF YOUR #NUIP
BEGIN TRAN --COMMIT  --ROLLBACK
DELETE FROM so_registros_civiles_nacimiento
JOIN #NUIP N ON N.NUIP = R.NUIP AND N.FECHA_REGISTRO = R.FECHA_REGISTRO
WHERE N.DUPLICATETOREMOVE = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical functions for this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NUIP ORDER BY FECHA_REGISTRO DESC) RN
    FROM registros_civiles_nacimiento
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

Comment: query have been executing for about 10 minutes and haven't finished yet. Are analytical functions this long to execute (Xeon 3.2, 4GB ram, 120.000 db rows).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use RANK() to create the result set ordered by date
2. Use WHERE EXISTS to delete from the source.

(Note: if you run the rank function over your duplicates, you should get your results. I've just referred to the whole table below)

This statement works in Oracle (replace the select * with delete if it works for you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM registros_civiles_nacimiento ALL_ 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM    
        (SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT  NUIP, 
                     FECHA_REGISTRO, 
                     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY NUIP ORDER BY FECHA_REGISTRO) AS ORDER_
             FROM registros_civiles_nacimiento)
         WHERE ORDER_ = 1) OLDEST
     WHERE   ALL_.NUIP = OLDEST.NUIP
     AND   ALL_.FECHA_REGISTRO = OLDEST.FECHA_REGISTRO);
```

Comment: as I state in my question. Server is Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @RandolfRincón-Fadul Yes I did see that, but the rank function is available in SQL Server, so this template should still be a valid approach for you.